# College Scorecard full data base

Tags: data-request, government, education, collegescorecard

The Obama administration recently release [College Scorecard Data](https://collegescorecard.ed.gov) with detailed information on college cost and earning after graduation. 
Does anybody know if the full data set is available for analysis? Or has somebody created a scraper (for me, ideally in R) to get the data?

Comment: I also edited your post to use the preferred tag "collegescorecard" for this data. The .gov web site links to this OpenData StackExchange site using that tag.

Comment: For meta discussion about the tags, see http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/q/324/1511

Comment: If anyone wants this in a package reachable with a `data()` command, let me know and I will upload it to CRAN. I assume most R users can load the data themselves but may be wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

College Scorecard Data:  https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/

- [Download all data](https://s3.amazonaws.com/ed-college-choice-public/CollegeScorecard_Raw_Data.zip) (~200 MB)
- [Documented API](https://collegescorecard.ed.gov/data/documentation/)
- [Github repo for website](https://github.com/18F/college-choice)